# Is $p\mapsto \|f\|_p$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\|f\|_p < \infty$ for all $1\leq p < p'$, I want to know if the the following is true and in that case how to show it

> $p \mapsto \|f\|_p$ is continuous on $[1,p')$

Or maybe we need to impose some more constraints such as finite measure space. In case of finite measure space, I tried to use [Egoroff's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It suffices to show $g(p) = \int_X |f|^p$ is continuous, because then $||f||_p = g(p)^{1 \over p} = e^{\log(g(p)) \over p}$ is continuous.

Note that $g(p) = \int_{|f| > 1} |f|^p + \int_{|f| \leq 1}|f|^p$. To show continuity of each term at some $p_0$, you can use the dominated convergence theorem; for some $\epsilon > 0$, $|f|^{p_0 + \epsilon}$ will serve as a dominating function for the first integral, and $|f|^{p_0 - \epsilon}$ will serve as a dominating function for the second (unless $p_0 = 1$ in which case just use $|f|$).

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about using DCT, but I got stuck on finding  a dominating function. The splitting part is great.

Comment: What if  $\int_X |f|^{p_0+\epsilon} d\mu=\infty$ ? In this case $|f|^{p_0+\epsilon}$ is not a dominating function

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is small enough it will finite; recall that $f \in L^p$ for all $1 \leq p \leq p'$ and $p = p_0$ is in this range.

Comment: @Zarrax How do we show that if $\epsilon$ is small enough the integral of $|f|^{p_0+\epsilon}$ will be finite?

Comment: Aaaah. I misread the question and didn't see the condition $\|f\|_p < \infty$ for all $1\leq p < p'$. Now it makes sense.  +1