# L-p space: p-norm proof

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Can somebody put me in the right direction to prove that:

$\lim_{p \to 1} \lVert f \rVert_{p}^p=\lVert f \rVert_{1}$ ?

Maybe this will be a beginning:

If $f \in$ $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)\cap \mathcal{L}^2(\mu)$, it follows that $f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$ for all $1\leq p\leq 2$.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Prove that [$p \mapsto \|f\|_p$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551309/continuity-of-norms-with-respect-to-p) on $[1,2]$ and then by continuity of $t \mapsto t^p$ we know that $p \mapsto \|f\|_p^p$ is continuous on $[1,2]$.

It follows that
$$\lim_{p \to 1} \lVert f \rVert_{p}^p=\lVert f \rVert_{1}$$