# Doesn't this $L^p$ norm estimate for all $p$ give me an $L^\infty$ bound?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> Let $r_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. We have that
>   $$\lVert v \rVert_{L^{r_n}(\Omega)} \leq C\lVert v \rVert_{L^{r_0}(\Omega)} < \infty$$
>   for all $n$, where $C$ is independent of $v$ and $n$.

Can I not just take $n \to \infty$ in this inequality to conclude that $v \in L^\infty(\Omega)$?  The reason I ask is, that the author of [this paper](http://paperity.org/p/6282988/l-estimates-for-nonlinear-elliptic-neumann-boundary-value-problems) (see page 300, where my $v$ is his $u^+$) proves after proving the above quoted statement that $v \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ by a proof by contradiction.

Comment: prove by contradiction that you can :-)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133773/is-p-mapsto-f-p-continuous or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551309/continuity-of-norms-with-respect-to-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You totally can, since $C$ is independent of $n$. Sometimes not doing so is illustratively useful, but you can.

Comment: Thanks.. any idea why the paper doesn't just use this around the inequality (4.19) (I don't see why it's useful to do it differently in this csae )

Comment: Ok, maybe the paper is just proving this fact (that the norm converges), and it has nothing to do with the particular problem in consideration.