# Let $f\geq 1$, Is the function $p\rightarrow \int |f|^p d\mu$ continuous

Tags: analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty[$ be a measurable function that is greater than or equal to $1$  for every $x\in X$ and $\mu$ be a positive measure on $X$. Consider the function $g:]0,\infty[\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ that sends $p$ to $\int_X f^pd\mu$, must $f$ be continuous ?

I think the answer is yes, but I did not succeed in finding anything useful. I prefer hints rather than full answers

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please do not close this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133773/is-p-mapsto-f-p-continuous. They are not duplicates

Comment: Could you clarify some things? Do you mean is f continuous in x for each p? What does g, a mapping of p, have to do with this?  And do we know if f or $f^p$ is integrable on $[0, \infty]$?

Comment: @BettyMock No. We do not know that $f^p$ is continuous. What do you mean by f continuous in x for each p ?

Comment: I don't know what I meant either.  Dan Fisher has dealt with it, and I now know what you were asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $g$ need not be continuous. It can have a jump discontinuity if you have an $f$ such that $\int_X f^{p_0}\,d\mu < \infty$, but $\int_X f^p\,d\mu = \infty$ for all $p > p_0$. An example for such an occurrence is

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x(\log x)^2}$$

on $(0,1/4)$. $f \in L^1((0,1/4))$, but $f \notin L^p((0,1/4))$ for all $p > 1$.

However, that is the only type of discontinuity that can occur, for points where $g$ is finite in a neighbourhood of $p$, the monotone convergence theorem asserts the continuity.

Comment: Hi Daniel, as usual you offer a lot of help to me. Do you agree with the answer of Zarrax in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133773/is-p-mapsto-f-p-continuous

Comment: Yes, that's right. The important difference is that there only the interval where $\int f^p < \infty$ was considered. On that interval we have continuity, and we also have continuity on the interval where $\int f^p = \infty$. But where the two intervals meet, we can have a jump.

Comment: Aaaah. I misread the question and didn't see the condition $\|f\|_p < \infty$ for all $1\leq p < p'$. Now it makes sense. Thanks Daniel +1