# $L^p$ continuous mapping problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f ∈ L_1 ∩ L_4$ (on some measure space). Prove that the function $[1,4] → R$ given by 
$p → ∥f∥_p$ is continuous.  This is a qualifying exam problem and I am not sure what to use.  All I can think of is Holder and that doesn't seem like much help.  I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: In the title you use a superscript for Lp, but in the question you use subscripts for L1 and L4, mind clarifying?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133773/is-p-mapsto-f-p-continuous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly true if $f$ is a simple function.  For general $f \in L^1 \cap L^4$, find a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^4$.  Show that $\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p$ uniformly in $p \in [1,4]$.  For the last part, use Holder's inequality to show that $\|f-f_n\|_p \le \|f-f_n\|_1 ^{1-\theta} \|f-f_n\|_4^\theta$ for $\theta$ satisfying $\frac1p = \frac{1-\theta}1 + \frac\theta4$.