# Is the mapping $ q \mapsto \|f\|_{L^q(U)}$ continuous?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I came up with this when trying to prove embeddings of $L^p(0,1)$ spaces. Suppose $U =(0,1)$ (or more generally  a bounded subset in  $\Re^n$). Is the mapping  $\phi = p \mapsto \|f\|_{L^p(U)}, \phi: [1,q] \rightarrow \Re$ continuous? Any ideas or counter examples?

Edit: This is not a duplicate with [Is $p\mapsto \|f\|_p$ continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133773/is-p-mapsto-f-p-continuous) because of different assumption on $f$!

Comment: What is restriction on $f$? It belongs to all $L^p$ spaces? Also what is $U$?

Comment: The point was to prove embedding $L^q(0,1) \subset L^p(0,1)$ for $1 \leq p \leq  q < \infty.$ So U here would be interval (0,1).

Comment: It's a fine question but the application seems a bit strange. If you know Hölder's inequality (or just Jensen's) then it is easy to show $\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|_q$ for $U=(0,1)$ and $1\leq p\leq q$. How would continuity help?

Comment: Similar question answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133773/is-p-mapsto-f-p-continuous - it doesn't cover continuity at the endpoint $q$ as stated, but the argument does work for the endpoint (just dominated convergence theorem)

Comment: When Hölder implies the finiteness of $\|f\|_1$ provided that $\|f\|_q < \infty$, then finiteness of  $\|f\|_p$ would be a direct consequence of continuity, when $p \in [1,q]$.

Comment: It is not exactly a duplicate as I don't assume the condition $\|f\|_p < \infty$ for all $p \in [1, q]$, rather it is my conclusion.